# Does "I can't address this job" mean "I can't do this job"?

Tags: verbs

Let's imagine a situation that I have to paint a house, but I can't do it by myself.

I would like to know if the phrase:

> "I can't address this job by myself"

means

> I can't do this job by myself"

Meaning, of course, that I need some help painting the house.

Comment: Address (verb): think about and begin to deal with (an issue or problem).
"a fundamental problem has still to be addressed"

So it fits.

Comment: @Inazuma thanks for your answer I really agree with you since the verb description says "to deal or cope with; handle problems" and in the example I really have to deal/cope with or handle a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use *address* to describe doing something. *address* is used to state how specific situations are handled.
For example, a politician might say:

> I agree that global warming is a serious problem, but I cannot **address** all of your concerns.
>   However, I will **address** the atmospheric changes, since this is my field of expertise.

You can check the verbal definitions for [address](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/address), which should help you understand how it can be used. The applicable definitions in the above examples would be:

> 5) to apply (oneself) or direct (one's energies)
>   6) to deal or cope with; handle (problems, issues, etc.)

Comment: I really think Inazuma is correct and that your answer has part of the answer to my question thank you so much for your help.